# capture my webcam and encode to mp4 with ffmpeg, but the x264 works bad

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, x264

**here is my version:**
ffmpeg version: 2.3.3
libx264 version:142.x

I wat to capture my video and use ffmpeg and x264 to a mp4 file. the solution is 320x240. 
But i found that the video file is so big. Then i found that the P frame and B frame is very big, even nearly equal to the I frame.I do not know why.

**here is my code:**

> ```
>     c->codec_id = codec_id;
>     c->bit_rate = 400000;
>     c->width    = 320;
>     c->height   = 240;
>     c->time_base.den = 10;
>     c->time_base.num = 1;
>     c->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
> ```

**Here is my program output:**

```
[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX 

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] profile High, level 1.3

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=400 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to '/home/2014_09_12/0002b6429579/5/2014_09_12_18_39_12_600.mp4':

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 400 kb/s, 10 tbc

    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s

[mp4 @ 0xb62005e0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.

[mp4 @ 0xb62005e0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.

[mp4 @ 0xb62005e0] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] frame I:3     Avg QP: 2.79  size: 72996

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] frame P:383   Avg QP: 0.14  size: 54075

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] frame B:216   Avg QP: 1.95  size: 64784

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] consecutive B-frames: 30.1% 63.2%  6.0%  0.7%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] mb I  I16..4: 16.1% 12.7% 71.2%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] mb P  I16..4:  3.5%  5.1% 15.9%  P16..4: 20.3% 22.8% 14.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:18.3%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  2.5%  8.2%  B16..8: 32.6% 19.8% 13.5%  
direct:22.2%  skip: 0.8%  L0:25.5% L1:12.8% BI:61.6%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] final ratefactor: -32.89

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] 8x8 transform intra:21.0% inter:29.6%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 100.0% 100.0% 100.0% inter: 83.3% 80.9% 80.9%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  5%  7% 42% 46%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 12% 23%  8%  6%  6%  8%  9% 14%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 11% 19% 10%  8%  8% 10% 10% 12%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 78%  3%  4% 15%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.5% UV:0.3%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] ref P L0: 43.4% 14.6% 19.0% 22.9%  0.1%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] ref B L0: 63.3% 35.7%  1.1%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] ref B L1: 97.0%  3.0%

[libx264 @ 0xb6200fc0] kb/s:4.53

[aac @ 0xb6201ba0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the newest demo, and then successed. The older version 2.0.4 demo muxing.c in doc/examples works bad in the 2.3.3 ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you encode in VFR (variable frame rate) mode and failed to provide correct pts to libx264 (about which there are hints from mp4 module). Because according to your output libx264 thinks that it encodes at ~4.5 kb/s while you asked it to encode it at 400 kb/s i.e. even at the lowest QPs it can't rich your target bitrate (and this is not over- but under-use of bitrate).